# .removeClass from all elements (versus a single defined element)

Tags: jquery, removeclass

how would I use .removeClass to remove all matching classes instead of calling out each element individually?

So instead of this:

```
$("input").removeClass("CO_form_alert");
$("select").removeClass("CO_form_alert");
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
$("input, select").removeClass("CO_form_alert");
```

or even

```
$(".CO_form_alert").removeClass("CO_form_alert");
```

Hint: jQuery always works on all selected elements.

Answer (score 6):

```
$(".CO_form_alert").removeClass("CO_form_alert");
```

Answer (score 3):

why couldn't you just use the following to do as you asked **remove the class from all elements (versus a single defined element)**

```
$(".CO_form_alert").removeClass("CO_form_alert");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify any number of selectors to perform the removeClass on:

```
$("select, input, banana").removeClass("CO_form_alert");
```