# How to remove all instances of a class in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, removeclass

I have this class called .m-active that is used multiple times throughout my HTML.

Basically what I want to do is remove all instances of that class when a user clicks on an image (which does not have the m-active class) and add the m-active class to that image.

For instance in a Backgrid row you might have a click handler as follows:

```
"click": function () {
    this.$el.addClass('m-active');
}
```

But you also want to remove that class from any rows to which it was previously added, so that only one row at a time has the .m-active class

Does anyone know how this can be done in javascript/jquery?

Comment: Yes, I have tried removeClass but I could not get it to do what I want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.removeClass from all elements (versus a single defined element)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899888/removeclass-from-all-elements-versus-a-single-defined-element)

Comment: The second part would be `$(this).addClass('m-active');`

Answer (score 62, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
$('.m-active').removeClass('m-active');
```

Explanation:

- Calling `$('.m-active')` selects all elements from the document that contain class `m-active`
- Whatever you chain after this selector **gets applied to all selected elements**
- Chaining the call with `removeClass('m-active')` removes class `m-active` from all of the selected elements

For documentation on this specific method, see: http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Getting grasp of the whole selector thing with jQuery is challenging at first, but once you get it, you see everything in very different light. I encourage you to take a look into some good jQuery tutorials. I personally recommend checking out Codeacademy's jQuery track: http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/jquery

Comment: Will this remove all of the instances of m-active that I have throughout my whole HTML file?

Comment: Yes in fact it does. See the explanation I added!

Comment: Great.  This is just what I needed and couldn't find when searching.  Thank you for explaining it as well (I am new to jquery/javascript/programming in general so this helped me)!

Answer (score 8):

all answers point to remove the class from the DOM element. But if you are asking to remove the element itself you can user `.remove()` jquery method

```
$('.m-active').remove();
```

[JQuery Remove Docs](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Answer (score 3):

In plain JavaScript (no jquery):

```js
for (elem of document.getElementsByClassName("m-active")) {
    elem.classList.remove("m-active");
}
```

Comment: There is an error here. elem needs to be declared with let, var or const. Still +1 because this answer helped

Answer (score 0):

**Jquery-:**

```
$("class").removeClass("your class");
```

**javascript-:**
Set the class name to nothing when you want to remove class in javascript!!!

```
document.getElementById("your id").className = "";
```

or

```
element.classList.remove("class name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically addressing the code block added to strengthen the quality of the question, and borrowing from jsalonen:

```
"click": function () {
    $('.m-active').removeClass('m-active');
    this.$el.addClass('m-active');
}
```